# closing a port in a running kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Im trying to create a load balancer service in kubernetes which will have 2 ports: `80` and `8080`. For the port 80 I want to open this port only when I want to use it. Is it possible to do this while the service is running?

Im trying to use `8080` for serving outside requests and `80` for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not exposing the debugging port at all by means of service (aspecially that you dont really know it will hit the same backing pod as port for real traffic). Instead it might be good enough for you to use `kubectl port-forward` to access the debug port when you need.